# Accented or special characters in RavenDB index

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I have several fields in my collection that contain accented characters, and the languages from which the words come are quite varied: Czech, German, Spanish, Finnish, Hungarian, etc.
I have noticed that when searching for, e.g. "Andalucía" (note the accented i), the query comes up empty - however, searching for "Andaluc*" returns what I am looking for.
I have found [this](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/indexes/using-analyzers) in the RavenDB docs, and wanted to ask if changing the field indexing method from *default* to *exact* would solve my problem.

Thanks !

EDIT: RavenDB appears to be dropping letters after AND including the accented character in the search. In the cmd window, I can see the query (which I enter from RavenDB Studio as `NAME_1:Andalucía`) coming out as `(...)/ByName?term=Andaluc&field=NAME_1&max(...)`

When I navigate to the terms of the index, I can see "andalucía" (lowercase !!). The index definition is simply a "`select new { NAME_1 = area.NAME_1 }`". Forgot to mention I'm still on RavenDB 3.5.

Index definition:

```
Map = areas => from area in areas
                               select new
                               {
                                   NAME_0 = area.NAME_0,
                                   NAME_1 = area.NAME_1
                               };
                Indexes.Add(x => x.NAME_1, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
                //Analyzers.Add(x => x.NAME_1, typeof(StandardAnalyzer).FullName);
```

The commented-out line doesn't work because the type StandardAnalyzer doesn't resolve in my VS2017 project. I'm curently looking into how to get either the dll or the correct *using* statement.
Querying for Andalucía in quotation marks results in the "correct query" being sent to Raven: `(...)/ByName?term=Andalucía&field=NAME_1&max=5(...)` - but produces no results.

FURTHER EDIT: Found the Lucene dll, included it in the project, used the StandardAnalyzer als the analyzer - same result (no results found).

On RavenDB 4, this appears fixed. meh

Comment: The terms of the index are lowercase also for me, but to me it works..maybe could be useful if you add the query and the index definition

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify that both '**Full-Text-Search**' and '**Suggestions**' options are 'turned on' in the index.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. If it's not default behaviour, then it wouldn't be turned on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the field you want the suggestions for.
Add this in your index definition:
`Suggestion(x => x.NAME_1);`

Comment: Suggestions won't help, as this is (most likely) related to the indexer or analyzer.  Even when turned on, the suggestions don't enable retrieval of the record in question. In the studio, the clickable link doesn't take me to the record.

Answer (score 0):

You must not have the following line of code in your index definition on the properties where you perform search operations:

```
Indexes.Add(x => x.PropertyXYZ, FieldIndexing.No);
```

By default if you didn't change the Indexing your query works.

Comment: Embri, I didn't exclude any fields from analysis.